# Rename an excel file and save it to a relative path with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I format through macros I recorded. The macros currently rename the file and save it to a constant path, but I need it to rename the file and save it to a relative path so that other teammates can use it. Are there any suggestions?

This is the active file

```
Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
```

This is the constant path

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\e6y550m\Documents\MANUAL RECS\Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Current code:

```
Sub Name_And_Save_Report()
'
' TO NAME, DATE AND SAVE THE REPORT AFTER IT HAS BEEN WORKED.
'
    Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Dim fname

    fname = InputBox("Enter your name (example-John):")    
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=thisWb.Path & "\" & fname & "_Manual Recon" & " " & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: "relative path"?  Relative to what?  (Or do you mean a shared directory somewhere?)  Obviously the answer is to replace `thisWb.Path` with whatever path you want, but there is nothing in the question to suggest what that will be, so it is going to be hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

So, you'll paste a copy of the workbook containing the above code in each persons folder.  When they open the workbook you want it to rename itself as:
*<< person name >>*_Manual Recon *<< mm.dd.yy >>*.xlsx

I assume you want the original file left in there so they can open it and create a new xlsx for the following day, but not create a file if it already exists (in case they open the xlsm twice in one day).

Another point to consider - is their personal folder given their name?
E.g. `G:\MMS Trade Payables\John`

I noticed in your code you set a variable `thisWb` to equal the `ActiveWorkbook`.
You could just use `ThisWorkbook` which always refers to the workbook that the code is running in.

So with these assumptions, try this code:

```
Sub Name_And_Save_Report()

    Dim fName As String
    Dim sNewFile As String

    'Get the folder name.
    fName = GetParentFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    'Could also get the Windows user name.
    'fName = Environ("username")

    'Or could get the Excel user name.
    'fname = application.username

    'Or could just ask them.
    'fname = InputBox("Enter your name (example-John):")

    sNewFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
        fName & "_Manual Recon " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsx"

    If Not FileExists(sNewFile) Then
        'Turn off alerts otherwise you'll get
        '"The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks...."
        '51 in the SaveAs means save in XLSX format.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs sNewFile, 51
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub

Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = oFSO.FileExists(FileName)
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Function

Public Function GetParentFolder(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetParentFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FilePath).Name
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

---

*I'll leave this here as my first answer:*

Do you mean something like this?
Using the `FileSystemObject` to recursively get the parent folder name.

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & vbCr & RelativePath(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2)

    'Will return "C:\Users\e6y550m" - step back 2 folders.
    MsgBox RelativePath("C:\Users\e6y550m\Documents\MANUAL RECS\", 2)

    'Your line of code:
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=RelativePath(thisWb.Path, 2) & "\" & fname & "_Manual Recon" & " " & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".xlsx"

End Sub

'FilePath - path to file, not including file name.
'GetParent - the number of folders in the path to go back to.
Public Function RelativePath(FilePath As String, Optional GetParent As Long) As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'If rightmost character is "\" then we've reached the root: C:\
    If GetParent = 0 Or Right(FilePath, 1) = Application.PathSeparator Then

        RelativePath = oFSO.GetFolder(FilePath)

        'If we've reached the root then remove the "\".
        If Right(RelativePath, 1) = Application.PathSeparator Then
            RelativePath = Left(RelativePath, Len(RelativePath) - 1)
        End If

    Else

        'GetParent is greater than 0 so call the RelativePath function again with
        'GetParent decreased by 1.
        RelativePath = RelativePath(oFSO.GetParentFolderName(FilePath), GetParent - 1)

    End If
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Darren Bartrup, your first answer worked perfectly! I will also try the second one in a bit as I want to fully understand both sets of code. Thank you for the detailed notes as they made it possible for me to completely understand the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if my question wasn't clear; I am a VBA novice at best.

'This is the current file that is already open,

```
Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
```

' I want to share this file with my teammates so they can use it. They all have different folders. I will place a copy of this workbook in each of their folders. When they use the copy that is in their personal folder, the macro needs to rename the workbook and save the renamed copy in their personal folder. The macro therefore needs code that will rename the workbook and save it in their folder without having a defined path. The shared drive path is G:\MMS Trade Payables. Within the MMS Trade Payables folder are the personal folders. I think the code just needs to activate the current workbook that is already open, rename it and save it in the current folder as an .xlsx instead of an .xlsm.

Current code:

```
Sub Name_And_Save_Report()
'
' TO NAME, DATE AND SAVE THE REPORT AFTER IT HAS BEEN WORKED.
'
    Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Dim fname

' Will use the fname variable to add the associates name to the file name (ex:If the associate enters Mark into the inputbox, fname will = Mark).  
    fname = InputBox("Enter your name (example-John):")  

' Makes thisWb = "Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm".
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook     
    Workbooks.Add

' Saves the active workbook ("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm") to the path of thisWb and renames the workbook by adding the fname value and the current date (ex: if the associate entered Mark as the value of fname, "Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm" becomes "Mark_Manual Recon 7.14.17.xlsx").
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=thisWb.Path & "\" & fname & "_Manual Recon" & " " & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY") & ".xlsx" 

' Closes the renamed workbook.
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

' Calls the original workbook and closes it.
    Windows("Manual Reconciliation Template.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Of course, this could be completely wrong since I am new to VBA.

Comment: You should edit your original question to include this extra information and delete this as an answer.